# Add PostGIS database information to XML generated by CartoDB

Tags: mapnik, osm2pgsql, cartocss

I have installed the latest Mapnik renderer following the information on their website and exported a .pbf file to a local PostGIS DB using this command:

```
osm2pgsql --style ../openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style --create --database gis -U maps -W -H 192.168.220.137 bucharest.osm.pbf
```

After this I generated a XML style sheet using `carto -a "3.0.0" ../openstreetmap-carto/project.mml > mapnik.xml`

Now I would like to use this mapnik.xml in a Python script to render a part of the exported map from PostGIS as a test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mapnik import *

mapfile = 'mapnik.xml'
map_output = 'mymap33.png'

m = Map(2048, 2048)
load_map(m, mapfile)
bbox=(Box2d( 26.08901,44.420234,26.125488,44.435067))

#m.zoom_to_box(bbox) 
render_to_file(m, map_output)
```

The problem is that the mapnik.xml has no information about my PostGIS DB (I looked in the file and I saw a lot of queries in  element but no host name, user name or password). How do I add more info about my PostGIS DB to this style sheet?

Comment: Check out the docs at https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PostGIS. Near the bottom there's an example of PostGIS config in XML.

Comment: Yep ... I've seen this example but the xml file generated by carto has over 35000 lines and adding information about my DB to it wont be so productive :)

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. If adding information about your DB won't be productive, why are you asking to "add more info about my PostGIS DB"? How many layers do you have?

Comment: You can provide the host name, user name and database name through the environment variables `PGHOST`, `PGUSER`, and `PGDATABASE`

Answer (score 1):

You should edit `project.mml` like below before generating mapnik.xml:

```
  osm2pgsql: &osm2pgsql
    type: "postgis"
    dbname: "gis"
    host: "localhost"
    user: "username"
    password: "password"
```